# Can different bounded context (BC) leave in one WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, domain-driven-design

We are building a system for managing our intern production of electrical goods manufacturing.

Regarding the complexity of our model, we think that DDD would be a good fit for our project.

The system is composed of a distributed web based system but also a heavy desktop application coded in WPF (using MVVM as presentation pattern).

I've just read the book "implementing domain driven design" ([http://www.amazon.com/dp/0321834577](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321834577)) from Vaughn Vernon (which is very good) and I'm quite confused because DDD seems to fit pretty well in web-based environments, *but is is the case for a WPF Desktop application?*

Being a rookie with DDD, I'm quite confused about the integration of DDD in a desktop application.

Given a lot of sources on DDD including the iDDD book, it is stated that BC should be decoupled from other BCs. The pattern for managing integration between different BC is often to create Open Host Service. OHS can be implement using REST, messaging or SOAP. I understand this for a distributed system with several web applications.

**But what if I have different BC inside one desktop application (WPF for the case)?**

The application has to cover a large set of context like "production monitoring", "production qualitiy", which for me sounds like different BC.

Is it OK to have several BC in the same windows application? Or 1 BC should be 1 application? (which seems to be often the case for distributed systems for

**What would be a good pattern for integrating different BC in one single desktop application?**

A solution seems to create a "event bus" inside my application and BC could communicate with each others by publishing / subscribing events on the bus. This implementation will look like Prism's EventAgreggator or mvvm light's Messenger, but dedicated to the model.

Udi Dahan proposes similar pattern in Domain Events Salvation http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/ but it seems to be limited to one BC

Comment: Kudos for the question effort, but there are so many questions here I don't think any one answer will be able to cover all in enough detail - short of actually writing a book. It would be better if you read up more on the subject and try to answer the questions yourself. Then come back with a smaller subset of questions.

Comment: The "Can different bounded context (BC) leave in one WPF application?" is very good, particularly subitem 2 (it does apply to all UIs, not only WPF UIs).  I have yet to see a convincing answer that avoids duplicating APIs all over the place, and I think it's worthwhile if the original author would ask that question again.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've edited my questions to focus only on the BC integration question.

Answer (score 0):

as you have read the DDD book by Vaughn Vernon, so know that DDD is all about tackling the complexity by understanding the problem first and solving it in Domain model.
it doesn't matter which technology or tools you are using (Note: it's recommended to use an object oriented language) to promote your application. 
we had the similar issue a few years ago (different BC inside one desktop application) and we used windows application for presenting. WPF is more flexible because of it's powerful binding feature witch let's you use MVVM patter and dependency injection.

Is it OK to have several BC in the same windows application? 
as I mentioned bounded contexts of DDD could be presented in one windows or web Application because they have their own service and repository implementation. 
don't assume bounded contexts of DDD as separate project! BCs could be successfully used in other project's Domain and not a separate project.

Comment: I think the original question is more about how one would integrate/work with the the different BCs from the UI.  More specifically:  How do you design the UI access to those BCs?  Do you create an extra facade atop of the different BCs such that your UI is oblivious to the different BCs?  Or do you call the BCs "directly", e.g., by sending BC-specific commands to a common event bus?  In the first case, a lot of extra complexity/code duplication is needed that might be overkill.  In the second case the UI is aware of the different BCs and is "tightly" coupled to them.  Best practices?

Comment: you can design different UI for each bounded context or a UI for different bounded context, it's based on your application. you can use event but or use CQRS patter for a bounded context in a solution. I recommend you to take look at this practice https://github.com/elbandit/DVD-Rental

Comment: Thanks for the hint at the DVD-Rental example.  It uses one UI per BC (e.g., the Subscription BC for the customers, and the Fullfillment BC/Operational UI for the staff, both of which are used by different parties -- staff vs. clients).  The original question asks what to do if a _single_ UI spans multiple BCs (e.g.,  "production monitoring" and "production qualitiy").  This is a natural demand because customers (including our own) naturally want to use _one_ application only, not twenty just because under the hood the architect decided to use twenty BCs.

Comment: For the UI / BCs communication, CQRS is a good fit as proposed by @Ehsan. The commands acts are used by UI to communicate with the model and that seems quite clean. It seems also to be the solution proposed as adapters in the hexagonal architecture.

Comment: But I'm still looking for a nice solution for the BCs communication with each others inside the same process. In a distributed architecture I understand that the use of queues and service bus (like rabbitMq and nServicebus) are great candidates for loosly coupled, persistant communication mechanism. The problem is that my WPF will be deployed several hundred times so we want to deploy less infrastructure as possible (for licencing and administration issues). I've come with an event bus inside the application, but I'm not sure it is the right solution to have decoupled BCs